# Array, prompt, if, if else statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, prompt

I'm trying to create a web page as below and the code is not working. Could anyone shed some light on it?

- Create a website that accomplishes the following:
- Create an array of your favorite bands.
- With a prompt, ask the user's favorite band.
- If it's one of your favorites, alert: "YEAH I LOVE THEM!"
- If it's not, alert: "Nah. They're pretty lame."
- **HINT:**  You will need to research how to use `.indexOf()`.
- **HINT:** You will need to research how to use `.toLowerCase()`.\

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Array Activity - Unsolved</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <script>



       var myBands = ["Chromatics","ACDC","Michael Jackson"];

       var UserGuess = prompt("Who is your favourite?");

       var userGuessLower = userGuess.toLowerCase(); 




        if (myBands.indexOf(userGuessLower) === -1) {
             alert("Na They're pretty lame.");
           }

        else {
             alert("OMG I love them too!");
           }

        </script>

        </body>

        </head>
        </html>
  ```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so `UserGuess` is not the same as `userGuess`.

Comment: The values in `myBands` need to be lower case too, or you will never find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error where you are using `userGuess` instead of `UserGuess`. Moreover, the purpose of using `toLowerCase()` is to remove the case sensitivity between the two strings when comparing, whereas what you are doing is changing the input to lower case while keeping the array elements to have some uppercase letters. Here is the solution:

```js
var myBands = ["chromatics","acdc","michael jackson"];
var UserGuess = prompt("Who is your favourite?");
var userGuessLower = UserGuess.toLowerCase(); 
if (myBands.indexOf(userGuessLower) === -1) {
     alert("Na They're pretty lame.");
}else {
     alert("OMG I love them too!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **UserGuess** must be **userGuess**. Because javascript is case sensitive.
2. You turned the output of prompt to lower case. it's okay. but you forgot to turn the elements of the array to lower case.